# X3D format viewer for Android

Tags: graphics

Is there any [X3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) format viewer for Android platform ?

Comment: Did you bother to [search in the Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=x3d&c=apps)?

Comment: @AlEverett I am not looking for 3D HD Wallpapaers. X3D is open 3D format but there are not many viewers for PC and I don't know any for Android.

Comment: The second app in the search Al linked to above is irrelevant (bad search results from Google there), but the first one is the exact same app noted in the answer Zuul gave below.

Comment: The link from Al gave me one result only ...

Comment: Might not be available in certain countries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Answer:

You can use [FreeX3D: VRML, X3D, STL viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.freex3d) by John Alexander Stewart available from Google Play Store:

> **FreeX3D is a 3D VRML/X3D and STL viewer for Android.**
>
> *NEW* - Anaglyph rendering option for 3D viewing of your 3D files!
>
> FreeX3D allows the user to browse local STL, VRML 97 and X3D files, and to view these files on their Android GLES-2 capable device. You can rotate or zoom STL files; X3D files you can walk, or examine, as defined by the spec. Use one finger to rotate or walk, two to zoom or move in +-Z, depending on navigation mode set.
>
> This version works on Android 2.2 and above. It **requires OpenGL ES-2.0**, which is available in all modern phones/tablets, and most released over the last couple of years.

[image: screen shots]

---

## Related curiosity:

There's also an interesting project that worth mentioning, called [X3DOM](http://www.x3dom.org) for free on Android devices that support WebGL:

> X3DOM (pronounced X-Freedom) is an experimental open source framework and runtime to support the ongoing discussion in the Web3D and W3C communities how an integration of HTML5 and declarative 3D content could look like. It tries to fulfill the current HTML5 specification for declarative 3D content and allows including X3D elements as part of any HTML5 DOM tree.

Comment: I installed latest Firefox for Andorid and tried to open examples from X3DOM webpage but Firefox crashed.

Comment: I don't know what device you're using, but either he doesn't have WebGL, or the render is to "heavy" for it.

Comment: Galaxy S3, I will give a try Nexus 7 ...